# Do constant functions have asymptotes?

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics

As far as I have learned a function has a horizontal asymptote $y = k$ if and only if 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = k$$ or $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = k$$

Now, for a constant function $$f(x) = c$$ we have $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = c$$

Does this mean that all constant functions have horizontal asymptotes, or is this definition not the one commonly used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you define asymptotes, and there was much discussion about this matter [in this question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/11418/teaching-asymptotes/).  It really comes down to whether or not we should have

$$f(x)=c$$

At only a countably infinite amount of times as $x\to\pm\infty$.  But for all intended purposes, I think stating a constant function is asymptotic to itself, or indeed, that any function is asymptotic to itself, is, though not very useful, acceptably correct by standard definitions.

Answer (score -3):

The function is defined everywhere. It would be an asymptote if the limit exists AND the function is not defined for that y value.

Comment: That's not true.  We can say $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is asymptotic to $|x|$ as $x\to\pm\infty$, for example.  More over, the function does not have to be defined everywhere.  $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt x}=0$$